# Prolog ~ Resolution involving the negation of some other statement?

Tags: prolog, negation

I have the following code, where I define is_max as the negation of is_below.

```
rank(mary,1).
rank(juan,2).
rank(john,3).
rank(jane,4).

is_below(X)   :- rank(X,A), rank(Y,B), A<B .
is_max(X)     :- not(is_below(X)) .
```

is_below is true if X is below someone in terms of rank. Therefore the person with the highest/max rank is someone for whom is_below is false (accordingly, is_max is defined).

When I query

```
is_max(jane) .
```

This is true (the above is false for mary, juan, and john)

However, when I query

```
is_max(X) .
```

This is false. I was expecting it to return jane. My logic seems to be fine, so I am not sure why I don't get jane. Any insight would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prolog has negation as failure. Think of it as 'not provable'.

`is_max(X)` would be true if `is_below(X)` would always be false. `is_below(X)` is true for X=mary, so `is_below(X)` is provable, and `is_max(X)` is false.

Because of this it's better to use notation `\+` instead of `not`, to remind yourself that it's not true `not`.

A possible way to fix your code is to explicitly instantiate X:

```
is_max(X) :- rank(X,_), \+ is_below(X).
```